# How do the new Missions work in CS GO?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

[image: Screenshot of Mission Item]

With the latest Patch and Operation Breakthrough Valve has introduced Missions to the game. As far as I can see you get 2 objectives with 1 Mission.

My question is, do the missions cycle over time? Or do you first have to complete all Missions before you get 2 new ones? How often will you be able to get a new Mission and do you need the operation badge to complete them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*As missions are quite new, I can only tell from my experience:*

### How missions work in general

Every mission explains itself in its short description. Most of them are "win a complete match on this specific map" or "get a number of kills in this specific game mode". After you completed this mission, you get rewarded with a weapon drop.

### A little bit more in detail

You do have 2 missions at start. Every mission is explained quite simple and in order to achieve it / get your reward you need to finish the map you would complete the mission - so don't leave to early.

For example: "Get 6 kills in game mode Destroy." This means you have to look for a game in this game mode. You will join a server and you likely will kill 6 people. After you have killed those guys, be sure you stay until this map is finished.

In the end screen score board, you will receive your mission reward as a weapon drop. (Since now I only got trash drops, I don't know if they cover up uncommon or rare items, too. All items seem to be out of the new added items, no old ones.)

### How to get new/more missions

For this you only have to play one supported game in the finding a game screen. This covers up match making, Gungame, Destroy and so on. In the end of the game, where weapons drop, you will now have an additional chance of a mission drop.

So if you need some missions, you may play a few Gungames, as they're finished quite fast and you get the chance for a mission drop after each game.

Comment: BTW do you lose the Operation coin after a mission is finished? Are mission coins useable during that certain time which the operation is occurring?

Comment: You wont lose your coin. The coin is just an indicator that you bought that "extra DLC". As you own the coin, youre able to join the operation-exclusive maps and exclusive item-drops (like these missions or the mission-branded treasure chest).